# How to verify which nuget version a particular DLL corresponds to?

Tags: c#, dll, nuget

Example given: we have a DLL:

[image: DLL Details]

How to check to which version of a particular **nuget** package from
[nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs/9.0.0-preview.1.24080.9#versions-body-tab)
this DLL corresponds to?

I thought this information is somehow inserted into DLL, but I haven't found any confirmation of that yet.

Is downloading of a particular nuget and comparing both DLLs the only way to verify?

Comment: It is configured by the package source, currently api.nuget.org/v3/index.json on my machine.  So if you have an old 2.x version of nuget then you'd just don't see the package.  It is unclear to me what problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

For DLLs in general, the way they version and the metadata is likely up to the publisher, so I would expect that not all DLLs have metadata that matches identically. However, the most popular ones (like Microsoft) usually follow semantic versioning.

Semantic versioning refers to the version that specifies three numbers in a specific format (major.minor.revision). In your example, the "Product version" shows "6.0.18+c76ac56..", so "6.0.18" appears to be the semantic version. The string that appears after that ("c76ac56") is most likely the git commit SHA which identifies the commit that was released in source code.

From nuget.org, you can navigate to the source code repository if it is available, and go to that commit to read the code. For System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs published by Microsoft, that code is located [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/main/src/libraries/System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs).

If you are only interested in the release notes, you can view them as well by clicking the link from nuget.org, and that is located [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/6.0/6.0.18/6.0.18.md) for version 6.0.18.